# Select subquery CHECK constraint DB2

Tags: db2, constraint

I have 2 tables: TVSHOW and ACTOR. I want to reject records if the inserted actor in TVSHOW does not exist in the ACTOR table using DB2.

```
db2 "ALTER TABLE TVSHOW ADD CONSTRAINT check_actor CHECK (actor in (select id from ACTOR))"
```

I keep running into, `During SQL processing it returned: SQL0546N  The check constraint "check_actor" is invalid.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use a subselect in a check constraint; you can only reference columns from the same table.

However, what you want to accomplish is what referential integrity constraints, also known as foreign keys, are for.

```
ALTER TABLE TVSHOW ADD CONSTRAINT actor_fk FOREIGN KEY (actor) REFERENCES ACTOR(id)
```

Presumably you have already defined a primary key constraint on `ACTOR.id`; if not, you need to define it, or a unique constraint on that column.